# Toggle DOM elements one after the other using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have the following code:

```
<div id="quotes">
    <p>"Quote 1."</p>
    <p>"Quote2!"</p>
    <p>"Quote3"</p>
    <p>"Etc"</p>
</div>
```

Is there an easy way to cycle through each quote so show quote 1 which then fades out to show quote2! etc or will i need to use a plugin?

Comment: I edited the demo a bit, hope you like it.

Comment: Obviously the solution is pretty easy without a plugin, gdoron's is nice  but doesn't repeat if that is a requirement.   I did add a plugin for you that maybe a little simpler and has options that you can set.  I did vote up gdoron's because of its simplicity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#quotes p').each(function(index){
    $(this).delay(index * 1000).fadeIn().fadeOut();
});
```

Or something like this:

```
$('#quotes p').hide().each(function(index){
    $(this).delay(index * 1600).fadeIn().delay(750).fadeOut();
});​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NThcn/2)

Answer (score 0):

1. keep the visibility of Q2, Q3, etc as "hidden".
2. give a delay for how long you want to show 1st quote then on callback, you can toggle the visibility of 1st and 2nd quote. Repeat the delay and callback inside this callback for the flow.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#quotes').find('p').hide();   

 $('#quotes').find('p').each(function(i){
        $(this).prev().fadeOut('slow');
        $(this).fadeIn('slow');
    });
```

Comment: This will not work, not just because you didn't terminated the selector string. [Your code DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NThcn/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Another options is to use a plugin.  The jQuery cycle plugin is great and super simple to setup:

It becomes a one liner:  `$('#quotes').cycle()`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lucuma/HsWrC/1/

Cycle Plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Reference (control time between, animation type, etc): http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html